# No muestra la imagen en etiqueta <img /> con el Path absoluto de la imagen - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc

Los datos se me guardan perfectamente en MySql, donde el **path** de la imagen En la base de datos figura así:

**Z:\MATERIAS\Laboratorio_IV\ASP.NET\Librery_MVC\Librery_MVC\principal\imagenes\ContraLosZombis.jpg**

Sin embargo cuando en la etiqueta `<img />` le indico esa ruta no se visualiza la imagen en la view.
(por las dudas aclaro que estoy utilizando el servidor local del visual studio)

Aquí el **Controller**:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LibroInsertado()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";
        Libro book = new Libro();
        book.Nombre = Request.Form["txt_bookName"];
        var nombreImagen = Request.Form["itf_urlImage"];
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/principal/imagenes/"), nombreImagen);
        book.UrlImagen = path;        
        return View(book);
    }
```

En `LibroInsertado.cshtml` hago la inserción del libro

```
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
LibroService ls = new LibroService();
int filasAfectadas;
filasAfectadas = ls.InsertBook(Model);
```

Y aquí en `Libros.cshtml` hago el listado de los libros que agregue anteriormente sin embargo la imagen no se visualiza.

```
<tbody>            
foreach (Libro item in Model)
{ 
    <tr>
        <th><img src="/@item.UrlImagen.Replace("\\", "/")" width="80" height="100" /></th>    
    </tr>                     
}
```

Comment: Escribe en tu código esto `<h1>@item.UrlImagen.Replace("\\", "/")</h1>` antes del `<img />`,ejecuta la aplicación de nuevo y dime que muestra.

Comment: Hola Rafael! muestra esto: Z:/MATERIAS/Laboratorio_IV/ASP.NET/Librery_MVC/Librery_MVC/principal/imagenes/ContraLosZombis.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para visualizar la imagen en un `<img src="" />`, debes indicar la **ruta relativa** y **NO** la **absoluta** como estas haciendo ahora.

Simplemente debes **eliminar** del **Path absoluto** de la imagen la dirección en el Servidor (`Server.MapPath("~")`).

El código sería así:

```
   foreach (Libro item in Model)
   { 
       <tr>
          <th>
             <img src="@item.UrlImagen.Substring(Server.MapPath("~").Length).Replace("\\", "/")" width="80" height="100" />
          </th>    
       </tr>                     
    }
```

> **Nota:** Tener en cuenta que el resultado en HTML debería ser así:
>
> ```
> <img src="/principal/imagenes/ContraLosZombis.jpg" width="80" height="100">
> ```
>
> o sea, la imagen debe estar en la ruta desde la raiz :
>   `/principal/imagenes/`

Answer (score 1):

No puedes cargar un archivo utilizando la ruta absoluta del servidor. Esto debido a que cuando una etiqueta `<img />` tiene una ruta local absoluta, digamos por ejemplo `c:/imagenes/1.tiff`, el navegador buscara el archivo en la ruta de la maquina del cliente, no en la del servidor.

En vez de retornar la ruta, retorna la imagen como tal desde el action para que la etiqueta `<img />` pueda cargarla.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult LibroInsertado() {
    ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";
    Libro book = new Libro();
    book.Nombre = Request.Form["txt_bookName"];

    return View(book);
}

[HttpGet]
public FileResult ObtenerImagen(string itf_urlImage) {
    var nombreImagen = itf_urlImage;
    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/principal/imagenes/"), nombreImagen);

    return File(path);
}
```

Entonces en el `img` indicas la ruta del action. Suponiendo que esten dentro del controlador `HomeController`:

```
foreach (Libro item in Model) { 
    <tr>
        <th><img src="~/home/obtenerImagen?itf_urlImage=123" width="80" height="100" /></th>    
    </tr>                     
}
```

Recuerda que en la ruta puedes enviar los parametros que necesites.

Comment: Gracias por responder!, pero me sale un error en la función ObtenerImagen en el return File(path), dice "ninguna sobrecarga para el método 'File' toma 1 argumentos.